# While using getOrDefault() I am not getting default Value

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

if i am providing some value in text box page then i am getting right output,
But if i don't provide any value in my text box i want that is will print default value.

For this I am using getOrDefault() method of Map class, but still iam not getting default value.

### StudentAdmissionController.java

```
package com.diwakar;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentAdmissionController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/admission.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAdmissionForm() {

        ModelAndView model =  new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/submitForm", method =  RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@RequestParam Map<String, String> reqParm) {

        String name  = reqParm. ("studentName", "Default Name");
        String hobby = reqParm.getOrDefault("studentHobby", "Default Hobby");

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionSuccess");
        model.addObject("msg", "Details submitted by you, Name : " + name + " and hobby is : " + hobby);
        return model;
    }
}
```

### spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">



<!--      <bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />
          <bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.diwakar.HelloController" />  -->

     <context:component-scan base-package="com.diwakar" />
     <mvc:annotation-driven />

     <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
     </bean>                    
</beans>
```

### Output is

Congratulations! Details has been submitted.

Details submitted by you, Name : and hobby is :

Instead of

Answer (score 0):

[getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) returns the default only if no mapping, you probably instead have a mapping to the empty string, you should check with custom code, perhaps building a method:

```
private static String getOrDefaultIfEmpty(Map<String,String> map, String key, String def)
    {
        String v = map.get(key);
        return v==null || v.length()==0 ? def : v;
    }
```

You need to do this check because an empty HTML text box sends as parameter an empty string that creates the mapping and for this reason you don't get the default value but instead an empty string.

Comment: Thanks @testo for your response, but if i want to check with this method alone, correct me if i wrong _this method Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or defaultValue if this map contains no mapping for the key. In my application there is a text box whose name is studentHobby and i am providing nothing there it will check if there is any value associate with that name, if not it will print the second argument which is default value_ 
**String hobby = reqParm.getOrDefault("studentHobby", "Default Hobby");**

Comment: Is the approach mentioned above is wrong,..? if it is then how.
I am not getting this. As per the oracle docs it should print 2nd argument i.e. default value. if i want to use this only 
**String hobby = reqParm.getOrDefault("studentHobby", "Default Hobby");**
Can anybody will help me out on this..?

Comment: I updated the answer. An empty text box sends an empty string, not "nothing"